# how to print lists inside tuple in python

Tags: python

i got lists inside a tuple. At least i think thats what i have (i did not code it):
`nvts = {"high": [], "medium": [], "low": [], "log": []}`
I want to print the values inside "high", "medium" etc.

i tried a for-loop:
`for a, *b in nvts:`
 `print(a, ' '.join(map(str, b)))`

but it gives me as an output:
`h i g h`
`m e di u m ...`

Can someone help me with the correct print?

best regards

Comment: seems to be a dictionary rather than a tuple

Comment: Programming questions can be asked on [so].

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand whether you want the values for each key, if so something like:

```
nvts = {"high": [], 
        "medium": ["value1"], 
        "low": ["value 2","value 3"], 
        "log": ["more value", "even more value"]}

print("\n".join([item for sublist in nvts.values() for item in sublist]))
```

outputs:

```
value1
value 2
value 3
more value
even more value
```

if you just want to print the keys:

```
print("\n".join(nvts.keys()))
```

outputs

```
high
medium
low
log
```

Comment: Please try to avoid answering off-topic questions. Doing so attracts more of them.

Comment: Ah i am sorry, next time i'll go for stack overlow. But thank you for the help Tom